# Install4J autostart function in api

Tags: java, install4j, autostart

I know there is an action to set launcher to autostart which is working fine.

But we need this functionality in the api of install4j to add/remove launcher programmatically from within java.

Is there any api for already and I overlooked it? If not are there any plans to add it to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 7.0, there is no such API, but you can add the "Add a startup executable on Windows and macOS" action to the "Startup" node of a custom installer application without any other screens and call that application from your code. On the "Launcher integration" tab of the custom installer application, click on the "Integration wizard" button, it will give you the code snippet for it.